# Installing php-memcached error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, memcached, rhel

I'm trying to install `php53u-pecl-memcached` and the following error ensues:

```
[root@host1]# yum install php53u-pecl-memcached
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
736 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php53u-pecl-memcached.x86_64 0:1.0.0-2.ius.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmemcached.so.2(libmemcached_2)(64bit) for package: php53u-pecl-memcached-1.0.0-2.ius.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmemcached.so.2()(64bit) for package: php53u-pecl-memcached-1.0.0-2.ius.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php53u-pecl-memcached-1.0.0-2.ius.el6.x86_64 (ius)
           Requires: libmemcached.so.2(libmemcached_2)(64bit)
Error: Package: php53u-pecl-memcached-1.0.0-2.ius.el6.x86_64 (ius)
           Requires: libmemcached.so.2()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Why is this happening? I have `memcached` and `libmemcached` installed:

```
[root@host1]# yum list installed | grep memca
libmemcached.x86_64              1.0.8-2.6.amzn1                      @amzn-main
memcached.x86_64                 1.4.13-1.11.amzn1                    @amzn-main
```

OS is `Amazon Linux AMI release 2013.09` on an aws instance.

Comment: Ever figure this out? I got similar libmemcached.so.2 errors installing another package.